# Ember.js - how to filter a model?

Tags: javascript, model, filter, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to figure out how to best approach creating a method to pull specific objects based on an attribute using Ember.js.

Right now my model looks like this:

App.Resume = Ember.Object.extend()

```
App.Resume.reopenClass
    store: {}

    findAll: ->
        arr = Ember.ArrayProxy.create()

        if xhr
            xhr.abort()
            return

        xhr = $.ajax(
            url: '../json/cv.json'
            dataType: 'json'
            timeout: 10000
            ).done (response) =>
                response.users.forEach (user, i) =>
                    cv = @findOne(user.personId)
                    cv.setProperties(user)
                    return
                values = (values for keys, values of @store)
                arr.set('content', values)

        arr

    findOne: (id) ->
        cv = @store[id]
        if not cv
            cv = App.Resume.create
                id: id
            @store[id] = cv
        cv
```

If you look at the loop inside the done callback you'll see that it is creating the model using user.id - there is also a user.specialization field. It is that field that I want to be able to filter by.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Rich

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filterProperty` on any Ember `Enumerable` like `Array` or `ArrayProxy`. It matches for presence by default. You can also pass in an argument to match against each property in the array. You can pair that with a computed property to bind against in your view.

```
filtered: function() {
  return this.get('products').filterProperty('outOfStock')
}.property('products')
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idamoz/2/) for an example.